# PL/SQL developer проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, oracle, plsql

Установил `PL/SQL developer`. Создаю записи в базе и казахские символы заменяются на `????`. На Oracle `SQL Developer` таких проблем нет. Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже такая проблема была. Исправил создав системную переменную `NLS_LANG` со значением `RUSSIN_CIS.UTF8`